# How did Tris feel when she came first in the rankings?

Tags: divergent

How did Tris feel when she found out she came first in the rankings?

Answer (score 3):

Based on what happens in the book, her mood is best described as *apprehensive* when she first tops the rankings. The former number one has recently lost an eye and although she realises that being first should be (in theory) cause for celebration, the reality is that it's just made the rest of her class that much more likely to hate her and to attack her.

> *I nod, still staring at the board. I should be pleased that I am
>   ranked first, but I know what that means. If Peter and his friends
>   hated me before, they will despise me now. Now I am Edward. It could
>   be my eye next. Or worse.*

Note that within seconds of the rankings being published, she is physically assaulted and threatened.

---

Later, when she learns her final score, her mood is substantially lighter. The high ranking confirms her initial impressions that choosing Dauntless was a wise move and that her divergence has largely been disguised:

> **A weight in my chest lifts. I didn’t realize it was there until it was
>   gone, and I didn’t have to feel it anymore. I smile, and a tingling
>   spreads through me.** First. Divergent or not, this faction is where I
>   belong.
>
> I forget about war; I forget about death. Will’s arms wrap around me
>   and he gives me a bear hug. I hear cheering and laughing and shouting.
>   Christina points at the screen, her eyes wide and filled with tears.